# Display previous date in a label compared to a selected date in text box (aspx+vb web Page)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a text box (datetxt.text) in which I am selecting a date as shown below:

[image]

I have another text box (datetxt1.text) in which I need one day before date.

I'm using ASPX with this VB code:

```
Protected Sub datetxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles datetxt.TextChanged
    datetxt1.text= datetxt-1   
End Sub
```

Comment: Will the text of the date always be in US format (mm/dd/yyyy)? If so, `datetxt1.Text = dateTxt.Value.AddDays(-1).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: Hi Andrew Morton. Thanks for the reply.  I am getting error code as 
value' is not a member of 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox'

Comment: Ah, from the picture I thought that the date was coming from some sort of datetimepicker control. You will need to use the [DateTime.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) to parse the date from the text, then you can use `.AddDays(-1).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")` on that to get a string representation of the previous date.

Comment: `datetxt` is a **textbox**, not a datetime, so the `datetxt-1` expression has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we have a text box (the date less 1 day), and then a textbox for selecting the date.

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreviousDate" runat="server">

        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyDate" runat="server" 
            TextMode="Date"
            OnTextChanged="txtMyDate_TextChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true"
         >
        </asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub txtMyDate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim MyDate As Date = txtMyDate.Text

    txtPreviousDate.Text = DateAdd("d", -1, MyDate)

End Sub
```

And result is this:

[image]

So, by casting the value to a date var type, then we can use date operations such as DateAdd() against that value.

Note that if you set textmode="date", then as above shows, the built-in asp.net date picker will show, and does so without any 3rd party add-ins.

However, since this is a simple date operation, then a better solution would be to use client side JavaScript for this purpose, since then we avoid a post-back (round trip) to the server.

In above, I included a autopost-back, as that will trigger the code when selecting/changing the date, but does result in a post-back, and depending on your needs, you may well not want that post-back and round tip.

You could place the 2 controls inside of a update panel if you not all that great using JavaScript code, and thus don't want to suffer a full page post-back for above to work.

So to prevent a full page post-back, then the above markup could become this:

First, right after the form tag, drag + drop in a script manager like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then drag in a Update Panel right before the 2 text boxes.

Our markup then looks like this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreviousDate" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyDate" runat="server"
                    TextMode="Date"
                    OnTextChanged="txtMyDate_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:TextBox>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, move your 2 text boxes inside of the content template.

So, now, you not suffer a full page post-back.